# Why is there not special handling for CASE WHEN NULL in SQL?

Tags: sql, null, language-design

In SQL it is impossible to compare a variable with NULL like this:

```
CASE x WHEN NULL THEN y ELSE z END
```

because with the three-valued SQL logic, `x = NULL` will *never* return true. One has to do this instead:

```
CASE WHEN x IS NULL THEN y ELSE z END
```

This is problematic when x is the result of a procedure that modifies the data for example:

```
CASE WHEN func(i) IS NULL THEN y
     WHEN func(i) = 'a'   THEN z
     ELSE                      t
 END
```

So… `func(i)` will be evaluated twice? Why is there no standard requirement that `CASE ... WHEN NULL` compares the evaluated expression to `NULL` with the `IS NULL` operator?

Are there DBMSes that allow such a construct?

Comment: Can you not introduce a temporary variable to hold the result of func(i) and use it in your case statement?

Comment: Because you're not guaranteed that the values after `WHEN` are just literals, there's no simple way to special case this without introducing more inconsistency, or re-writing SQL so that NULL==NULL. E.g. if the expression is `CASE func(i) WHEN Col1 THEN...` and `Col1` is null in some rows, but not in others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're not guaranteed that the values after WHEN are just literals, there's no simple way to special case this without introducing more inconsistency, or re-writing SQL so that NULL==NULL.

E.g. if the expression is `CASE func(i) WHEN Col1 THEN...` and `Col1` is null in some rows, but not in others...

Answer (score 3):

This is just one of the many reasons NULL is evil. One work-around is to choose a magic value as a surrogate for NULL:

```
CASE COALESCE(func(i), 'nada') WHEN 'nada' THEN y WHEN 'a' THEN z ELSE t END
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a RDBMS that allows you to to get around this on a `case` statement.

In Oracle you can swap to the decode function:

```
decode( func(i), null, 'y', 'a', 'z')
```

Whilst Null != Null is normal SQL, it is considered equal when using a Decode statement within your logic.

Comment: Thanks, `DECODE` is indeed a function that handles it correctly. Unfortunately even Tom advises [not to use it](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1243867216406)

Comment: On the basis it is deprecated way back when, but still not removed in 11gr2, and I suspect will still not be removed in 12. Personally I avoid using Decode, but due to reasons of portability.